# How to keep georeferencing from ArcGIS when importing raster into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, georeferencing, import

I tried searching for the answer to this, but I didn't see anything, so here it goes:

I have previously georeferenced some .png raster images in ArcGIS 10.2.2, and could like to import them into QGIS. When I tried doing this, the raster would load, but it was not georeferenced.

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this? (And yes, all the relevant files from ArcMap are in the folder, as I moved the entire folder to the new computer with QGIS).

Comment: Is your Project menu>Project Properties>CRS>Enable on the fly CRS transformation option checked?  I was able to georeference a png in Arc and bring it into QGIS with no problems.

Comment: Yes, it is checked. However, the problem has been solved by Dan C below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGIS and ArcGIS use two different file extensions for a .PNG image's world file. When you georeference a PNG in ArcGIS, it generates a .PGWX file containing the spatial information for the PNG. QGIS uses the extension .PNGW instead. You can just rename your image's .PGWX files to .PNGW files and they should come in to QGIS correctly.

Comment: Just tried georeferencing an image in Arc and it created a PGW world file (on v10.2.2) and loaded into QGIS with no problems.

Comment: @artwork21 I'm using 10.2.0, I don't know if that's the difference?

Comment: @user32690 If that answered your question, all you need to do is click the check mark to the left of the answer, that will mark that as the Accepted answer in case anyone else has this problem in the future. I went ahead and edited the question to reverse your edit wherein you added the answer to the question text.